# Wat does the "vkCreateSwapchainKHR:internal drawable creation failed." means

Tags: vulkan

I am always stuck at the swapchain creation, and I don't know why. I enabled the validation layers, and the best anwser I got is:

- vkCreateSwapchainKHR: internal drawable creation failed

I have an Nvidia GTX960 card. i ran some vulkan samples on it so, It must support vulkan.

Here is my swapchain creator function:

```
void Renderer::createSwapChain(VkSwapchainKHR *swapchain,VkPhysicalDevice *dev,VkDevice *vulk_dev,VkSurfaceKHR *surface, uint32_t family_index,VkExtent2D *extent) {
    uint32_t format_count;
    VkFormat format;

    VkBool32 support;
    vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceSupportKHR(*dev, family_index, *surface, &support);
    if (!support) {
        fprintf(*Renderer::error_log, "%d :Surface is not supported.", __LINE__);
        fclose(*Renderer::error_log);
        exit(-1);
    }

    vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormatsKHR(*dev, *surface, &format_count, nullptr);
    vector<VkSurfaceFormatKHR> surface_format(format_count);
    vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormatsKHR(*dev, *surface, &format_count, surface_format.data());

    if( 1 == format_count && surface_format[0].format == VK_FORMAT_UNDEFINED) {
        format = VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
        infos.format.color_format = VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
    }else {
        format = surface_format[0].format;
    }

    VkFormat depth_format = VK_FORMAT_D16_UNORM;
    VkFormatProperties format_props;
    vkGetPhysicalDeviceFormatProperties(*dev, depth_format, &format_props);
    if (format_props.linearTilingFeatures & VK_FORMAT_FEATURE_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_BIT) {
        infos.tiling = VK_IMAGE_TILING_LINEAR;
    }else if (format_props.optimalTilingFeatures & VK_FORMAT_FEATURE_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_BIT) {
        infos.tiling = VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL;
    }else {
        fprintf(*Renderer::error_log, "%d: VK_FORMAT_D16_UNORM is not supported",__LINE__);
        fclose(*Renderer::error_log);
        exit(-1);
    }

    VkPresentModeKHR present_mode_selected = VK_PRESENT_MODE_FIFO_KHR;
    uint32_t present_modes_c;

    vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfacePresentModesKHR(*dev, *surface, &present_modes_c, nullptr);
    vector<VkPresentModeKHR> present_modes(present_modes_c);
    vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfacePresentModesKHR(*dev, *surface,&present_modes_c,present_modes.data());
    for (int i = 0; i < present_modes_c; i++) {
        if (present_modes[i] == VK_PRESENT_MODE_MAILBOX_KHR) {
            cout << "Mailbox supported." << endl;
            present_mode_selected = VK_PRESENT_MODE_MAILBOX_KHR;
        }
    }
    VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR capabilities;
    vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR(*dev, *surface, &capabilities);

    if (capabilities.maxImageExtent.width < (*extent).width) {
        (*extent).width = capabilities.maxImageExtent.width;
    }
    if (capabilities.maxImageExtent.height < (*extent).height) {
        (*extent).height = capabilities.maxImageExtent.height;
    }
    VkCompositeAlphaFlagBitsKHR composite_alpha = VK_COMPOSITE_ALPHA_OPAQUE_BIT_KHR;
    if (capabilities.supportedCompositeAlpha & VK_COMPOSITE_ALPHA_OPAQUE_BIT_KHR) {
        composite_alpha = VK_COMPOSITE_ALPHA_OPAQUE_BIT_KHR;
    }else if (capabilities.supportedCompositeAlpha & VK_COMPOSITE_ALPHA_INHERIT_BIT_KHR) {
        composite_alpha =VK_COMPOSITE_ALPHA_INHERIT_BIT_KHR;
    }
    VkSurfaceTransformFlagBitsKHR transform;
    if (capabilities.supportedTransforms & VK_SURFACE_TRANSFORM_IDENTITY_BIT_KHR) {
        transform = VK_SURFACE_TRANSFORM_IDENTITY_BIT_KHR;
    }else {
        transform = capabilities.currentTransform;
    }

    VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR swapchain_ci = {};
    swapchain_ci.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SWAPCHAIN_CREATE_INFO_KHR;
    swapchain_ci.pNext = NULL;
    swapchain_ci.surface = *surface;
    swapchain_ci.minImageCount = capabilities.minImageCount;
    swapchain_ci.imageFormat = format;
    swapchain_ci.imageExtent = capabilities.currentExtent;
    swapchain_ci.preTransform = transform;
    swapchain_ci.compositeAlpha = composite_alpha;
    swapchain_ci.imageArrayLayers = 1;
    swapchain_ci.presentMode = present_mode_selected;
    swapchain_ci.oldSwapchain = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
    swapchain_ci.clipped = true;
    swapchain_ci.imageColorSpace = VK_COLORSPACE_SRGB_NONLINEAR_KHR;
    swapchain_ci.imageUsage = VK_IMAGE_USAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_BIT;
    swapchain_ci.imageSharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;
    swapchain_ci.queueFamilyIndexCount = 0;

    if (VK_SUCCESS != vkCreateSwapchainKHR(*vulk_dev, &swapchain_ci, nullptr, swapchain)) {
        fprintf(*Renderer::error_log, "%d: Couldn't create Swapchain", __LINE__);
        fclose(*Renderer::error_log);
        exit(-1);
    }else {
        cout << "Swapchain created successfully" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would gradually mutate a working sample's swapchain creation code to match your swapchain creation code, and find out at which point it breaks.

Comment: PS: What return code does the command return? And what is your platform (OS, driver version, SDK)?

Comment: Some notes: 1) You don't need to pass handles as pointers 2) You **must** check `VkResult`s from all the commands 3) You don't need to `(* ).`; there is a `->` operator 4) Technically there's no guarantee `VK_COMPOSITE_ALPHA_OPAQUE_BIT_KHR` is supported as you assume 5) Similarly the transform 6) The `swapchain_ci.imageExtent = capabilities.currentExtent;` does not account for the special value of `capabilities.currentExtent`

Comment: OS:Windows 10 drive version: 376.33 SDK: Vulkan 1.0.37 VK_ERROR_VALIDATION_FAILED_EXT

Comment: That's suspicious. Does your debug callback return VK_FALSE? Or how do you set up validation layers?  Does it return that with validation layers + debug extension off too?

Comment: Did you find the fix?

Answer (score 7):

I recently had this exact same problem, the problem was caused by OpenGL context in a GLFW window.

So if you happen to be using GLFW, include a line

```
glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API );
```

before you create a window.