# vkCreateSwapchainKHR Error

Tags: c++, windows, vulkan

Even though validation layers and debug callback extensions are enabled and working (they respond to wrong structs etc.), I'm still getting a "VK_ERROR_VALIDATION_FAILED_EXT" result from `vkCreateSwapchainKHR()`, and there's no validation layer error to pinpoint the mistake...
Swap chain creation (using GTX 970 ) :

```
VkBool32 isSupported = false;
vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceSupportKHR( physicalDevices[0], 0, surface, &isSupported);

if (!isSupported) {
    std::cout << "*ERROR* This device doesn't support surfaces" << std::endl;
}

VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR surfCaps;
vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR(physicalDevices[0], surface, &surfCaps);

std::vector<VkSurfaceFormatKHR> deviceFormats;
uint32_t formatCount;
vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormatsKHR(physicalDevices[0], surface, &formatCount, nullptr);
deviceFormats.resize(formatCount);
vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceFormatsKHR(physicalDevices[0], surface, &formatCount, deviceFormats.data());


swapChainInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SWAPCHAIN_CREATE_INFO_KHR;
swapChainInfo.pNext = nullptr;
swapChainInfo.flags = 0;
swapChainInfo.surface = surface;

swapChainInfo.minImageCount = surfCaps.minImageCount; 
swapChainInfo.imageFormat = VK_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
swapChainInfo.imageColorSpace = VK_COLOR_SPACE_SRGB_NONLINEAR_KHR;
swapChainInfo.imageExtent = surfCaps.currentExtent;
swapChainInfo.imageArrayLayers = 1;
swapChainInfo.imageUsage = VK_IMAGE_USAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_BIT;
swapChainInfo.imageSharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;

swapChainInfo.queueFamilyIndexCount = 0;
swapChainInfo.pQueueFamilyIndices = VK_NULL_HANDLE;
swapChainInfo.preTransform = VK_SURFACE_TRANSFORM_IDENTITY_BIT_KHR; 
swapChainInfo.compositeAlpha = VK_COMPOSITE_ALPHA_OPAQUE_BIT_KHR;
swapChainInfo.presentMode = VK_PRESENT_MODE_FIFO_KHR;
swapChainInfo.clipped = VK_TRUE; // TODO : TEST clipping against another window
swapChainInfo.oldSwapchain = VK_NULL_HANDLE;

result = vkCreateSwapchainKHR( device, &swapChainInfo, nullptr, &swapChain );
if (result) {
    std::cout << "*ERROR* Swapchain Creation Failed :" << result << std::endl;
}
```

Surface Creation using GLFW (Which doesn't return any error):

```
if (result = glfwCreateWindowSurface(instance, window, nullptr, &surface)) 
    {
        std::cout << "*ERROR* Surface Creation Failed : " << result << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: Does it return the same error with layers disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a huge number of reasons validation of `vkCreateSwapchainKHR` will fail (check out `PreCallValidateCreateSwapchainKHR` in [core_validation.cpp](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/blob/master/layers/core_validation.cpp)).

There may not be enough code here to tell why it is failing, for example, the failure might be because of an invalid surface. But, to pinpoint the problem, it should give a failure message in the debug log, which will tell you exactly why. You should enable it by calling `CreateDebugReportCallbackEXT`, before trying to create the swapchain. This will also require you to enable the `VK_EXT_debug_report` extension. See [here](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Setup/Validation_layers) for details.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i do get validation errors in console when i use unavailable/invalid features in structs, but didn't manage it with CreateDebugReportCallbackEXT it may reveal more i'll check it.

Comment: Using CreateDebugReportCallbackEXT I got the validation error "internal drawable creation failed" which led me to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41379529/wat-does-the-vkcreateswapchainkhrinternal-drawable-creation-failed-means

Answer (score 1):

Just a few points about your code (potentially cause of problems):

- You are not checking `VkResult` of all the `vkGet*` commands
- You are not checking `swapChainInfo.imageFormat` against supported formats in your `deviceFormats`
- You are not accounting for the situation that `surfCaps.currentExtent` can be `0xFFFFFFFF`
- `swapChainInfo.pQueueFamilyIndices` is a pointer not a handle; use `nullptr`
- You are not checking `swapChainInfo.preTransform` against `surfCaps.supportedTransforms`
- You are not checking `swapChainInfo.compositeAlpha` against `surfCaps.supportedCompositeAlpha`

Comment: Thanks for reply, capturing result on previous commands is a good point i'll check it out once i rewrite the whole thing (accidentally deleted the project folder...), and about those checks you mentioned, as far as i tested them, they're all available in my graphics card/surface and using the wrong features causes a validation error.

Comment: c̶a̶u̶s̶e̶s̶   **should** cause a validation error. Do not assume the validation layers are complete and bugless.

Comment: Thanks for help, issue was GLFW creating an OpenGL context. 
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41379529/wat-does-the-vkcreateswapchainkhrinternal-drawable-creation-failed-means