# vkCreateSwapchainKHR: internal drawable creation failed

Tags: c++, glfw, vulkan

I had my Vulkan application working but for some reason it stopped working(I don't believe I touched anything that could have broken it, besides making my engine project a .lib instead of a .dll) and started giving the "vkCreateSwapchainKHR: internal drawable creation failed" error in the validation layers. `vkCreateSwapchainKHR` returns `VK_ERROR_VALIDATION_FAILED_EXT`.

I already checked this answer:
[Wat does the "vkCreateSwapchainKHR:internal drawable creation failed." means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41379529/wat-does-the-vkcreateswapchainkhrinternal-drawable-creation-failed-means), but it was not my problem, (as I said, it was working until it wasn't). Here's all the code I believe is relevant, if you need something else just comment:

Window Creation:

```
/* Initialize the library */
if (!glfwInit())

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DECORATED, _WCI.IsDecorated);
    GLFWWindow = glfwCreateWindow(Extent.Width, Extent.Height, _WCI.Name.c_str(), nullptr, nullptr);

    if (!GLFWWindow) glfwTerminate();

    //glfwMakeContextCurrent(GLFWWindow);

    uint32 Count = 0;
    auto ff = glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions(&Count);

    GS_BASIC_LOG_MESSAGE("GLFW required extensions:")
    for (uint8 i = 0; i < Count; ++i)
    {
        GS_BASIC_LOG_MESSAGE("%d: %s", i, ff[i]);
    }

    WindowObject = glfwGetWin32Window(GLFWWindow);
    WindowInstance = GetModuleHandle(nullptr);
```

I'm using the correct instance extensions:

```
const char* Extensions[] = { VK_KHR_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME, VK_KHR_WIN32_SURFACE_EXTENSION_NAME, VK_EXT_DEBUG_UTILS_EXTENSION_NAME };
```

```
VKSwapchainCreator VulkanRenderContext::CreateSwapchain(VKDevice* _Device, VkSwapchainKHR _OldSwapchain) const
{
    VkSwapchainCreateInfoKHR SwapchainCreateInfo = { VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SWAPCHAIN_CREATE_INFO_KHR };

    SwapchainCreateInfo.surface = Surface.GetHandle();
    SwapchainCreateInfo.minImageCount = 3;
    SwapchainCreateInfo.imageFormat = Format.format;
    SwapchainCreateInfo.imageColorSpace = Format.colorSpace;
    SwapchainCreateInfo.imageExtent = Extent2DToVkExtent2D(RenderExtent);
    //The imageArrayLayers specifies the amount of layers each image consists of. This is always 1 unless you are developing a stereoscopic 3D application.
    SwapchainCreateInfo.imageArrayLayers = 1;
    SwapchainCreateInfo.imageUsage = VK_IMAGE_USAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_BIT;
    SwapchainCreateInfo.imageSharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;
    SwapchainCreateInfo.queueFamilyIndexCount = 0;
    SwapchainCreateInfo.pQueueFamilyIndices = nullptr;
    SwapchainCreateInfo.preTransform = VK_SURFACE_TRANSFORM_IDENTITY_BIT_KHR;
    SwapchainCreateInfo.compositeAlpha = VK_COMPOSITE_ALPHA_OPAQUE_BIT_KHR;
    SwapchainCreateInfo.presentMode = PresentMode;
    SwapchainCreateInfo.clipped = VK_TRUE;
    SwapchainCreateInfo.oldSwapchain = _OldSwapchain;

    return VKSwapchainCreator(_Device, &SwapchainCreateInfo);
}
```

Both `VK_SURFACE_TRANSFORM_IDENTITY_BIT_KHR` and `VK_COMPOSITE_ALPHA_OPAQUE_BIT_KHR` are supported by my GPU.

```
    VkBool32 Supports = 0;
    vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceSupportKHR(_PD, PresentationQueue.GetQueueIndex(), _Surface, &Supports);

    VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR SurfaceCapabilities = {};
    vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR(_PD, _Surface, &SurfaceCapabilities);

    VkBool32 Supported = 0;
    vkGetPhysicalDeviceSurfaceSupportKHR(_PD, PresentationQueue.GetQueueIndex(), _Surface, &Supported);

    auto bb = vkGetPhysicalDeviceWin32PresentationSupportKHR(_PD, PresentationQueue.GetQueueIndex());
```

Everything here returns true, although it seemed suspicious to me that `VkSurfaceCapabilitiesKHR` returned the same extent for currentExtent, minImageExtent and maxImageExtent.

Comment: `vkCreateSwapchainKHR` does not require that much boilerplate, so I suggest you make a minimal complete example. Your swapchain creation code shows almost nothing as it takes values from elsewhere we cannot see.

Comment: You should check `SwapchainCreateInfo.minImageCount` though against limit.

Comment: With glfw, you should be using the platform agnostic `glfwGetPhysicalDevicePresentationSupport`. Also do `glfwVulkanSupported`. Make sure you are not doing any magic with the window; Vulkan driver can be particular about its state. E.g. try commenting out the `GLFW_DECORATED`.

Comment: @krOoze My minImageCount is 2. And I tried commenting out GLFW_DECORATED and it made no difference. Isn't vkGetPhysicalDeviceWin32PresentationSupportKHR the same as glfwGetPhysicalDevicePresentationSupport? I'll try the rest when I get home, but as I said it was working and it suddenly stopped.

Comment: Also, my VkSurface handle value has an extremely high value, isn't that unusual? The last times I ran the application the value used to be much lower, something as 2 or 3.

Comment: It is same except it is multiplatform. Except any magic that GLFW might do. Notably the function can return GLFW errors on top of what the vk function does. Yes, high `VkSurface` is suspicious; it indicates your Validation Layers do not work (or are disabled). Or you forgot to `vkCreate*` it and it is uninitialized value. PS: image count also has a top limit; `3` should usually fit but technically you should check it anyway in a well behaved code.

Comment: @krOoze I ran all of the GLFW check functions and this is what I got: ```[Time: 20:02:33]Vulkan support: 1
[Time: 20:02:33]GLFW required extensions:
[Time: 20:02:33]0: VK_KHR_surface
[Time: 20:02:33]1: VK_KHR_win32_surface
[Time: 20:02:33]Vulkan: (null), vkCreateSwapchainKHR: internal drawable creation failed
[Time: 20:02:33]glfwGetPhysicalDevicePresentationSupport: 1``` I commented out GLFW_DECORATED and checked if the VkSurfaceKHR handle was being initialized to 0, then set by Vulkan and it was. Also my ```SwapchainCreateInfo.minImageCount``` is 8. I'll create a separate simpler project

Comment: @krOoze I did the separate Vulkan project and everything went well. No errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* Initialize the library */
if (!glfwInit())

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DECORATED, _WCI.IsDecorated);
```

If this is your actual code, it means "if `glfwInit()` succeeds skip `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API);`". And as we know not calling the hint causes the error.

The `if` should perhaps not have negation inside. And (this not being Python) it should have scope `{}` to cover all the init code.

Comment: Oh, thank you @krOoze. Sorry to bother you with such a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to remove the `glfwInit` call from inside the `if` and place it outside.

`if (!glfwInit())` -> `glfwInit()`

No idea why, if someone knows why this could've have caused the problem I would love to know.

Comment: Lol, actually you have it negated in the if. So the glfw hint is skipped, which makes this exact duplicate of the Question you link.